# Data image can't show

Tags: html, angularjs

I try how to implement this code from this link http://blog.hfarazm.com/angularjs-routeparams/

But I have problem on show image in my slider

This is my controller

```
.controller('HomeController',['dataProvider','$scope','$location', '$modal', '$log', 'authService', '$http',
    function(dataProvider, $scope, $location,$modal, $log, authService, $http){
        $http.get('/data/data-slider.json').success (function(data){
            $scope.imagesliderVariable = data;
            $scope.orderGuitar = 'price';
        }); 
}]);
```

This my view

```
<carousel>
        <slide ng-repeat="slide in imagesliderVariable" active="slide.active" index="$index">
            <img ng-src="/uploads/home/{{slide.image}}.jpg" style="margin:auto;">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4>Slide </h4>
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </slide>
    </carousel>
```

In prompt my app didn't show an error but image can't show, so whats my problem code? Beforely I say thank you Advance.

Comment: Can you console.log(data) and provide your json response

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `then`:

```
.controller('HomeController',['dataProvider','$scope','$location', '$modal', '$log', 'authService', '$http',
    function(dataProvider, $scope, $location,$modal, $log, authService, $http){
        $scope.imagesliderVariable = [];

        $http.get('/data/data-slider.json').then(function(data){
            $scope.imagesliderVariable = data;
            $scope.orderGuitar = 'price';
        }); 
}]);
```

Comment: Still can't show an image and still without error on prompt

Comment: are you sure you are getting something? can you log the `data`?

Comment: Yes I'm sure, I log the data, log can get a data and on my view still can't view an image